# Error when .count() result == 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I have column named **Le type cycle** which can take two values : **P: production** or **S: service**
and I do have other column named **Matricule** which identify employees, so Im looking to count the occurence number of **P** for each employee **Matricule: index**

I used this formula :

```py
df.groupby(['Matricule','Le Type Cycle'])['Le Type Cycle'].get_group((index, prod)).count()
```

It counts correctly when `P` exist but when it doesn't it shows error `KeyError: (285, 'P')`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right:

```
df = df[df['Le type cycle'] == 'P']
df.groupby('Matricule').count()
```